# При запуске ReactJS приложения на Thymeleaf отображается пустая страница

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, thymeleaf

Я пытаюсь сделать фронтовое приложение с помощью ReactJs и Spring ThymeLeaf(как шаблонизатор). Посматривая в Туториал https://habr.com/ru/post/321552/
вот структура приложения [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT8WO.png)

файл webpack.config.js

```
var packageJSON = require('./package.json');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './index.jsx',
    output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'generated'),
    filename: 'app-bundle.js'},
    resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']},
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true}),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development")
        }
    })
],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
},
devServer: {
    noInfo: false,
    quiet: false,
    lazy: false,
    watchOptions: {
        poll: true
    }
}
}
```

Файл .babelrc

```
{
 "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
 "plugins": ["transform-regenerator"]
}
```

Файл package.json

```
{
  "name": "expense-manager",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "webpack -d",
     "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base app/",
     "test": "react-scripts test",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Файл index.jsx

```
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
ReactDom.render(<label>Hello, World!</label>, document.getElementById('react'));
```

И файл greeting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; 
charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Hello demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{./js/src/main/expense- 
  manager/generated/app-bundle.js}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div th:id="react"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Никаких ошибок при запуске команды npm run build нет. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am5qb.png)

В браузере тоже никаких ошибок
Но при загрузке страницы я вижу только пустую страницу
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frO05.png)
Уже все перепробовал, ничего не помогает.
Есть предположение что просто ReactJs у меня не работает или не собирается, потому что когда я запускаю скрипт `npm run dev` очень долго происходит сборка и 
папка distr остается пустая